# How to get html structure with user input in php in order to download pdf

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I am trying to save HTML div as pdf in javascript and PHP. I have tried a lot of libraries, but all of them are returning to the pdf-only HTML structure. The page I want to convert to pdf is generated from a database table in which I have put everything for well structure HTML. Now I am at the point where I can serialize all my input data in string like `action=saveWorkPermit&text_CLMC_491=1515&date_CLMC_494l495d=2021-12-06&time_CLMC_496l497t=10%3A34&`. I also can get them in array as {"action": "saveWorkPermit", "text_CLMC_491": "1515" ...}. I have my HTML structure also and then. I am stuck. I do not know how to input in the HTML the values and then get this result HTML and put it in some pdf function. I will really appreciate your answers if you can help me. Here is the Ajax code:

```
                case "GeneratePdf":
                    var ex = data.details.structure ; // here it is the html
    
                    var array = data.details.data; // this is the data as array
                    for (var key in array) {
                        var type = key.split("_")[0];
                        var value = array[key];
                        if(type == 'check' && value == 'on') {
                            $("#"+key).prop("checked", true);
                        } else if (type == 'gr'){
                            $("input[name="+key+"][value=" + value + "]").prop('checked', true);
                        } else {
                            $("[name='"+key+"']").val(value);
                        }
                        
                    }

                    let mywindow = window.open('', 'SAVE', 'height=650,width=900,top=100,left=150');
                    mywindow.document.write(`<html><head><title>MyPdf</title>`);
                    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                    var params2 = $("#AllWP").serialize();
                    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("AllWP").innerHTML); // one more time the html structure
                    mywindow.document.write(params2);   // this is the serialized data
                    mywindow.document.write(ex);    // because of this line it is not working
                    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    mywindow.document.close(); 
                    mywindow.focus(); 
                    mywindow.print();
                    mywindow.close();
                break;
```

This is one of the forms I want to export as pdf:
[image: form]

If there is no way to do that in javascript, I can also get the above data in PHP and loop them there.

The main question is if I have HTML like this :

```
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2half "> 
<label for="text_CLMC_494l495d">Дата на започване:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 "> 
<input type="date" id="text_CLMC_494l495d" name="date_CLMC_494l495d" size="0" placeholder="">
</div>
```

and data like this: `..&text_CLMC_494l495d=1515&..`
How can I have this:

```
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2half "> 
<label for="text_CLMC_494l495d">Дата на започване:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 "> 
<input type="text" id="text_CLMC_494l495d" name="text_CLMC_494l495d" size="0" placeholder="">1515</input>
</div>
```

Here it is what I have - the first one is the html, the second one are the values with its HTML names:
[image: data]

Here it is the text from `data` picture:

```
<div id="allwpunic">
    <input type="hidden" value="saveWorkPermit" name="action" id="action">
<div class="clmc_header">
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-sm-2 "> 
<img src="/assets/images/logotita.png" alt="logo_img">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 "> 
<h1>ПЛАН ЗА КРИТИЧНО ПОВДИГАНЕ ОТ МОБИЛЕН КРАН №</h1> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding"> 
<h4>ОР No:</h4> 
</div><div class="col-sm-2 "> 
<input type="text" style="max-width:100%;" id="text_CLMC_491" name="text_CLMC_491" size="10" placeholder="">
</div></div><div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2half "> 
<label for="date_CLMC_494l495d">Дата на започване:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 "> 
<input type="date" id="date_CLMC_494l495d" name="date_CLMC_494l495d" size="0" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding"> 
<label for="time_CLMC_496l497t">От:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 "> 
<input type="time" id="time_CLMC_496l497t" name="time_CLMC_496l497t" size="0" placeholder="">
</div><div class="col-sm-1 nopadding"> 
<label for="time_CLMC_498l499t">До:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 "> 
<input type="time" id="time_CLMC_498l499t" name="time_CLMC_498l499t" size="0" placeholder="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-sm-3 "> 
<label for="text_CLMC_502l503t">Отдел/ място, където ще се работи:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 "> 
<input type="text" style="max-width:100%;" id="text_CLMC_502l503t" name="text_CLMC_502l503t" size="85" placeholder="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-sm-3 "> 
<label for="text_CLMC_506l507t">Кранът е осигурен от:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 "> 
<input type="text" style="max-width:100%;" id="text_CLMC_506l507t" name="text_CLMC_506l507t" size="85" placeholder="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row spacer">
<div class="col-sm-3 "> 
<label for="text_CLMC_510l511t">Описание на работата:</label> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 "> 
<input type="text" style="max-width:100%;" id="text_CLMC_510l511t" name="text_CLMC_510l511t" size="85" placeholder="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
action: "saveWorkPermit"
date_CLMC_494l495d: "2021-12-08"
language: "en"
text_CLMC_491: "49846498"
text_CLMC_502l503t: "Някъде"
text_CLMC_506l507t: "Нещо си"
text_CLMC_510l511t: "Тестов пример"
time_CLMC_496l497t: "10:01"
time_CLMC_498l499t: "02:56"
```

Comment: There is no AJAX code shown. Ajax sends data to the server... you're just opening a new browser window. Also it's unclear what output you actually want. Give sample data and expected html output

Comment: The case  "GeneratePdf": is in Ajax function, but I did not write it, sorry.

Comment: Well this code takes data directly from the page, not from the server, so it's hard to see how Ajax would be relevant in any case. But anyway, you have not really explained the problem. You say you want to see the form in the PDF...but do you want to see the original form as shown in your picture, or do you want to see the data from the form, displayed in a different way? Please give a clear indication of the expected output.

Comment: There is no problem in what order and style the data will be display. My main problem is how to put in html structure the values. The desired result is label: value, no matter style. I will update my question one more time to get clearly.

Comment: You want to make another `<input type="text"` to put in the PDF? Why? You cannot input into a PDF. Why not make a simple div or span?

Comment: But anyway, what problem is occurring in your code right now? You said one part is "not working", but that doesn't tell us much. What output do you get right now? We don't know the content of `data` is, so it's hard to understand what the code will do

Comment: The data is array with html names and corresponding values. I do not want to make new input type, I just want html with values in it and then generate pdf with this html.

Comment: Please give an actual sample of the data rather than just describing it! That's much easier to understand.

Comment: `I do not want to make new input type`...then why did you ask `How can I have this... <input type="text" id="text_CLMC_494l495d"....`? That looks like a new input to me.

Comment: As per [ask], please provide all code data examples as _text_. Data from pictures cannot be copied, searched, or re-used in answers and examples. Showing us the content of `data` in JSON format would be a good way,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here is the function which helped me: (it works with textarea, checkbox, radio button, input type text, date, time and dropdowns):

```
case "GeneratePdf":
                    const e = document.getElementById("AllWP"),
                        npts = e.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea"); // vsi4ki vyzmokni tagove
                    if (npts) {
                        npts.forEach((npt) => {
                            var rch = npt.getAttribute("type"); // samo za checkbox i radio types
                            var others = npt.tagName.toLowerCase();

                            if (rch == "radio" && npt.checked) {    
                                npt.setAttribute("checked", true);
                            } else if (rch == "checkbox" && npt.checked) {
                                npt.setAttribute("checked", true);
                            } else {
                                switch (others) {
                                    case "input":
                                        npt.setAttribute("value", npt.value);
                                        break;
                                    case "select":
                                        const optns = npt.querySelectorAll("option"),
                                            pre_slctd = npt.querySelector("[selected]");
                                        if (pre_slctd) {
                                            pre_slctd.removeAttribute("selected");
                                        }
                                        optns[npt.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
                                        break;
                                    case "textarea": 
                                        npt.textContent = npt.value; 
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("No inputs in ", "AllWP");
                    }

                    let mywindow = window.open('', 'SAVE', 'height=650,width=900,top=100,left=150');
                    mywindow.document.write(`<html><head><title>MyPdf</title>`);
                    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                    mywindow.document.write(e.outerHTML);
                    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
                    mywindow.print();
                    mywindow.close();
                    break;
```